# Is there a way to replace a character in a vector with a NULL value in R?

Tags: r, vector, replace, null, stringr

There's a lot of pages that show how to replace a `NULL` value with either `NA` or a specific value, but I haven't seen anything that shows how to goes the other way (replacing a value with `NULL` in a vector). Is there a way to do this? Here's a reprex of my `{tidyverse}` attempt:

```r
library(tidyverse)

# character vectors can have null values
c("None", "Some", NULL, "Many", "All")
#> [1] "None" "Some" "Many" "All"

# but is there a way to replace a string in a vector with null?
c("None", "Some", "NULL", "Many", "All") %>%
  str_replace("NULL", NULL)
#> Error: `replacement` must be a character vector
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: You can't replace a string with NULL because NULL has zero-length. In your first example the character vector does not contain a NULL value - it contains nothing where you specified NULL because NULL is, literally, nothing. There is a function `as.null()` which will simply turn anything you give it into a single NULL.

Comment: Your first statement isn't itself a character vector. It's a call the function `c` with 5 arguments, the third being `NULL` and rest being length-1 character vectors. `c` ignores the `NULL`, concatenates everything else, and returns the resulting length-4 character vector. There is no `NULL` hiding in the result.

Comment: If you're coming from SQL, note that a SQL `NULL` is the same as an R `NA`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's worth remembering the difference between `NULL` and `NA`. `NA` values are a dodgy value, `NULL` is no value whatsoever. In order to get the second output to be the same as the first output, you would have something the same as the following

```
column <- c("None", "Some", "NULL", "Many", "All")
column <- column[column != "NULL"]
```

This creates a shorter vector, which is why str_replace doesn't like it.

Answer (score 4):

Character vectors can't contain NULL but we can work around this in several ways.

1. convert the character vector to a list in which case NULL can be an element

   ```
    x <- c("None", "Some", "NULL", "Many", "All")
    x_list <- replace(as.list(x), x == "NULL", list(NULL))

    str(x_list)
    ## List of 5
    ##  $ : chr "None"
    ##  $ : chr "Some"
    ##  $ : NULL
    ##  $ : chr "Many"
    ##  $ : chr "All"
   ```
2. If there are no zero length strings then use that to represent NULL.  This is quite common with R providing the `nzchar` function to test for this -- it returns TRUE for character strings of non-zero length and FALSE otherwise.

   ```
    x <- c("None", "Some", "NULL", "Many", "All")
    x2 <- replace(x, x == "NULL", "")

    x2
    ## [1] "None" "Some" ""     "Many" "All" 

    nzchar(x2)
    ## [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
   ```
3. Use NA instead of NULL.

   ```
    x <- c("None", "Some", "NULL", "Many", "All")
    replace(x, x == "NULL", NA)
    ## [1] "None" "Some" NA     "Many" "All"
   ```
4. Another approach is to use two vectors.  One for the data and one to indicate whether the value is missing.  Then the value in the null component can be anything.

   ```
    x <- c("None", "Some", "NULL", "Many", "All")
    x_null <- c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE)
   ```
5. A number of packages can handle multiple types of missing values. The memisc package uses an S4 class, `"character.item"`, for this.

   ```
    library(memisc)

    xx <- x
    missing.values(xx) <- "NULL"

    xx
    ## Item (measurement: nominal, type: character, length = 5) 
    ##
    ## [1:5] None Some *NULL Many All

    is.missing(xx)
    ## [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
   ```

   The naniar package represents different kinds of missing values in
   a column of a data frame using a second column and the labelled
   package uses attributes for this.

   See the [Missing Data Task View](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/MissingData.html) for information on other
   missing value packages as well.